# The attribute 'amp-boilerplate' may not appear in tag 'style amp-custom'

Tags: html

Running into a failure when testing with the AMP Gmail Playground (https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/): The attribute 'amp-boilerplate' may not appear in tag 'style amp-custom'.

However, the amp-boilerplate tag isn't nested inside of the amp-custom style tag, any thoughts on how to resolve this?

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style amp-custom>@media only screen and (max-width:480px){h1,h2,h3,h4{line-height:1.1}body{width:100%;min-width:100%}#bodyCell{padding:0}table.kmDesktopOnly,table.kmMobileHide,td.kmDesktopOnly,td.kmDesktopWrapHeaderMobileNone,th.kmDesktopOnly,tr.kmDesktopOnly{display:none}table.kmMobileOnly{display:table}tr.kmMobileOnly{display:table-row}td.kmDesktopWrapHeader,td.kmMobileOnly,th.kmMobileOnly{display:table-cell}table.kmMobileNoAlign,tr.kmMobileNoAlign{float:none;text-align:initial;vertical-align:middle;table-layout:fixed}tr.kmMobileCenterAlign{float:none;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;table-layout:fixed}td.kmButtonCollection,td.kmButtonCollectionInner{padding:9px}img.kmMobileHeaderStackDesktopNone,td.kmMobileHeaderStack,td.kmMobileHeaderStackDesktopNone{display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;padding-bottom:9px;padding-right:0;padding-left:0}td.kmMobileWrapHeader,td.kmMobileWrapHeaderDesktopNone{display:inline-block}td.kmMobileHeaderSpacing{padding-right:10px}td.kmMobileHeaderNoSpacing{padding-right:0}table.kmDesktopAutoWidth{width:inherit}img.kmImage,table.kmBoxedTextContentContainer,table.kmColumnContainer,table.kmMobileAutoWidth,table.kmSplitContentLeftContentContainer,table.kmSplitContentRightContentContainer,table.kmTextContentContainer,table.kmVerticalButton,table.kmVerticalButtonContent,td.kmVerticalButtonBarContentOuter table.kmButtonBarContent,td.kmVerticalButtonCollectionContentOuter table.kmButtonCollectionContent{width:100%}td.kmImageContent,td.kmMobileStretch{padding-left:0;padding-right:0}td.kmVerticalButtonContentOuter,td.kmVerticalButtonIconContent,td.kmVerticalButtonTextContent{padding-left:0;padding-right:0;padding-bottom:9px}table.kmColumnContainer td.kmTextContent,table.kmSplitContentLeftContentContainer td.kmImageContent,table.kmSplitContentLeftContentContainer td.kmTextContent,table.kmSplitContentRightContentContainer td.kmImageContent,table.kmSplitContentRightContentContainer td.kmTextContent{padding-top:9px}td.rowContainer.kmFloatLeft,td.rowContainer.kmFloatLeft.firstColumn,td.rowContainer.kmFloatLeft.lastColumn{float:left;clear:both;width:100%}div.templateContainer,div.templateContainer.brandingContainer,table.templateContainer,table.templateContainer.brandingContainer,table.templateRow{max-width:600px;width:100%}h1{font-size:40px}h2{font-size:32px}h3{font-size:24px}h4{font-size:18px}td.kmTextContent{font-size:14px;line-height:1.3}td.kmTextBlockInner td.kmTextContent{padding-right:18px;padding-left:18px}table.kmTableBlock.kmTableMobile td.kmTableBlockInner{padding-left:9px;padding-right:9px}table.kmTableBlock.kmTableMobile td.kmTableBlockInner .kmTextContent{font-size:14px;line-height:1.3;padding-left:4px;padding-right:4px}}span.yshortcuts:active,span.yshortcuts:focus,span.yshortcuts:hover{background-color:none;border:none}.rowContainer .kmTextContent a{color:#c9acaa;font-weight:400;text-decoration:underline}.kmTable .kmTableRow:last-child>td{border-bottom:none}</style>
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style>
  </head>
```